# Из инфиксной формы в постфиксную и префиксную

Tags: java, алгоритм, любой-язык

Помогите пожалуйста формулами для преобразования алгебраических выражений из инфиксных форм в постфиксные и префиксные с предусмотрением вхождения выражений с различными приоритетами и скобками.

Comment: польская запись?) алгоритм на википедии есть

Comment: Сам когда-то писал калькулятор.
Советую почитать про польскую запись/нотацию.
Алгоритм Дейкстры для перевода в польскую нотацию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для постфиксной: [алгоритм сортировочной станции (вики)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

Там есть подробное описание, а по первой [ссылке](http://www.chris-j.co.uk/parsing.ph) доступен пример на java.

Для префиксной:

- Имеем на входе формулу в инфиксной форме: a+b/(c-d);
- Перепишем формулу справа налево: (d-c)/b+a;
- Воспользуемся алгоритмом постфиксной трансляции, получим: dc-b/a+;
- Полученную формулу перепишем справа налево, получим формулу в префиксной записи: +a/b-cd.

Найдено [тут](http://www.cyberforum.ru/pascal/thread83937.html).